# python qrcode decode getting output?

Tags: python, qr-code

Hi there i have managed to create a qr code and then read it again. However on reading it i get lots of extra information that i do not want such as the width and hieght of the qr code image that was decoded. How do i just get the first part of the result?

My code :

```
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode



import pyqrcode
qr = pyqrcode.create("example")
qr.png("test1.png", scale=6)

data = decode(Image.open('test1.png'))

print(data)
```

my output on running of the code :

```
[Decoded(data=b'example', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=24, top=24, width=126, height=126), polygon=[Point(x=24, y=24), Point(x=24, y=150), Point(x=150, y=150), Point(x=150, y=24)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

`decode()` returns a list of `Decoded` objects, so I would simply try this:

```
decoded_list = decode(Image.open('test1.png'))
print(decoded_list[0].data)
```

I renamed your "`data`" variable to avoid confusion with the `data` attribute of a `Decoded` object.